# Using a JS Proxy around ApiPromise

Tags: polkadot-js

I would like to use a standard JS `Proxy` around `ApiPromise`, basically to add my own fields to the object without having to extend it. I have some issues doing the following:

```
const proxied = new Proxy(
  new ApiPromise({ provider: new WsProvider() }),
  {
    something: () => "test"
  }
)

console.log("something=", proxied.something())

await proxied.isReady
```

My first `console.log` executes correctly and then on the next line it fails with the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read private member #isReadyPromise from an object whose class did not declare it`

The above comes from internally to the `ApiPromise`, specifically `@polkadot/api/promise/Api.js:162:17`. Is there a specific step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a known issue with [JS private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) and [JS Proxy objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). If you have some time to spare, you can read a [quite lengthy discussion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/106) on it at TC39.

I have actually seen this out in the wild before with non-explicit proxies introduced by [Vue 3 refs](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4656). The "quite lengthy discussion" above does help for the general case, since it mentions a pattern which seems to work -

```js
const proxied = new Proxy(
  new ApiPromise({ ... }),
  {
    // getter target for build-in API properties, returns it directly on
    // target if found, otherwise defers to the implementation provided
    get (target, prop, _receiver) {
      return prop in target
        ? target[prop]
        : this[prop];
    },
    // any extras you wish to add
    something: () => 'test'
  }
);
```

I tested the above addition the code  you provided and it does seem to do what is expected, logging both the output from `something()` as well as `isReady` not failing. Additionally could also subscribe to new blocks directly on `proxied`.

I know you did mention it in passing, but an `class MyApi extends ApiPromise { ... }` would also have the desired effect of adding new methods, without having the above work-around for Proxy + private fields. This is generally the approach I would go for, but it obviously depends on your specific usage.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'll try both - the Proxy approach is just historic (a couple of months elsewhere), but I guess it may make more sense not to.